# Remove duplicate key but keep object where other key is lowest with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have recently shifted to `MongoDB` and `Mongoose` with `Node.js`. And I am wrapping my head around it all coming from `SQL`.

I have a collection where documents have a similar structure to the following:

```
{
    name: String
    rank: Number
}
```

Sometimes the `name` might be the same, but the `rank` will always be different.

I would like to remove all duplicates of `name`, but retain the object that has the **LOWEST** `rank`.

For instance, if my collection looked like this:

```
{
    name: "name1"
    rank: 3
},
{
    name: "name1"
    rank: 4
},
{
    name: "name1"
    rank: 2
}
```

I would like to remove all objects where `name` is the same except for:

```
{
    name: "name1"
    rank: 2
}
```

Is this possible to do with mongoose?

Comment: Is this a one-time cleanup or something you are looking to do as a regular workflow of the app (eg when writing inserting/updating)?

Comment: Sort of both. I would like it to be a part of my function, which I will run once a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```
const found = await db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      minRank: {
        $min: "$rank"
      }
    }
  },
])


await db.collection.deleteMany({ 
  $or: found.map(item => ({
    name: item._id,
    rank: { $ne: item.minRank }
  }))
})
```

**Explanation:**

From my point of view your solution would result in many unnecessary calls being made, which would result in a terrible time of execution. My solution exactly contains two steps:

1. find for each document's property `name` the corresponding lowest `rank` available.
2. delete each document, where the name is equal to one of those names **and** the rank is not equal to the actual lowest rank found.

**Additional notes:**

If not already done, you should probably define an index on the `name` property of your schema for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out using `aggregate`:

```
const duplicates = await collectionName.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      dups: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: { $gt: 1 }
    }
  }
]);

duplicates.forEach(async (item) => {
  const duplicate_names = item.dups;
  const duplicate_name = await collectionName.find({ _id: { $in: duplicate_names } }).sort({ rank: 1 });

  duplicate_name.shift();

  duplicate_name.forEach(async (item) => {
    await collectionName.deleteOne({ _id: item._id });
  });
});
```